# Desarrollar una aplicación en C para cambiar permisos de un archivo y/o directorio. En Linux

Tags: c, linux, gnu

La verdad no es por culpar al docente pero en todas las clases el solo muestra el código sin explicar mas, busco en foros y sitios web pero la verdad ando bien perdido. Si alguien podría ayudarme con esa consigna por favor. Solo quisiera que me instruyan en donde buscar información para hacer un programa en C que haga lo de arriba.

Comment: Incluye en tu proyecto sys/stat.h y usa chmod, sinceramente, has buscado poco.

Comment: Revisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539710/how-to-change-show-permissions-in-c#2539736